# Emacs Lisp variables scoping

Tags: function, lambda, scope, elisp, lexical-scope

Let's consider the following functions:

```
    (defun test (x)
      "X."
      (request "http://example.com"
        :parser 'json-read
        :complete (cl-function
                   (lambda (&key response &allow-other-keys)
                     (message "%s" x)))))

    (defun test2 (x)
      "X."
      (funcall (cl-function (lambda (z) (message "%s" z))) x))
```

Calling `(test2 3)` Works fine and produces the desired message. Calling `(test 3)`, however, fails with the following error:

```
error in process sentinel: let*: Symbol’s value as variable is void: x
error in process sentinel: Symbol’s value as variable is void: x
```

My guess is that `request` is a macro doing something weird to variable scoping. Unfortunately, the documentation does not mention anything like this. Is there a way to overcome that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request` is probably an ordinary function.

The problem is that the `lambda` you pass to it is not called immediately but is
saved and called later:

```
(defun make-function (x)
  (lambda () (message "received %s" x)))
=> make-function
(defconst f (make-function 3))
=> f
(funcall f)
=> Lisp error: (void-variable x)
```

`x` that `make-function` bound no longer exists.

This is because by default Emacs uses [*dynamic binding*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dynamic-Binding.html) and you need [*lexical binding*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html) to get the behavior you want.

If you [add](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html)

```
;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
```

to [the first line of your file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html), it will be *compiled* with lexical binding and
the code above will produce the message `received 3` instead of an error.

Comment: When I add this to the top of the file, I get `symbols's value as variable is void: -*-` when I try to evaluate it with `eval-buffer`.

Comment: @Sventimir: (1) I expected your file to begin with comments ;-) (2) please _compile_ and load the file (`C-u C-x C-f`)

Comment: Okay, when the line is commented out, it works. Thanks a lot!